# Is there a way to capture/scrape the text content programmatically on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, screen-scraping, screenshot

Similar to taking a screenshot programmatically, except, I want just the text contents on the screen.  I guess I could put the screenshot through an OCR, but, I am hoping there's a better solution.

Comment: Can I give the OCR Code Reference for it?

Comment: @user1673099 Haha, sure, if you have a good one :)

Comment: https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing it take the UIWindow instance and traverse through all the views in the window and check whether they are subclass of UILabel and UITextField or UITextView, if they are you can take the text from there.

Comment: Can I get another app's UIWindow instance from my app (assuming my app/service has the right permissions?)